# Efficient computation of similarity matrix in Python (NumPy)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, similarity

Let `X` be a `Bxn` `numpy` matrix, i.e.,

```
import numpy as np
B = 10
n = 2
X = np.random.random((B, n))
```

Now, I'm interested in computing the so-called kernel (or even similarity) matrix `K`, which is of shape `BxB`, and its `{i,j}`-th element is given as follows:

K(i,j) = fun(x_i, x_j)

where `x_t` denotes the `t`-th row of matrix `X` and `fun` is some function of `x_i`, `x_j`. For instance, this function could be the so-called RBF function, i.e.,

K(i,j) = exp(-|x_i - x_j|^2).

For doing so, a naive way would be the following:

```
K = np.zeros((B, B))
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    x_i = X[i, :]
    for j in range(X.shape[0]):
        x_j = X[j, :]
        K[i, j] = np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(x_i - x_j, 2) ** 2)
```

What I want is to do the above operation in a vectorized way, for the sake of efficiency. Could you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can due this using only numpy. I would use the method [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) from the scipy library, something like this:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
B=5
X=np.random.rand(B*B).reshape((B,B))
dist = cdist(X, X, metric='euclidean')
K = np.exp(dist)

dist
array([[ 0.        ,  1.2659804 ,  0.98231231,  0.80089176,  1.19326493],
       [ 1.2659804 ,  0.        ,  0.72658078,  0.80618767,  0.3776364 ],
       [ 0.98231231,  0.72658078,  0.        ,  0.70205336,  0.81352455],
       [ 0.80089176,  0.80618767,  0.70205336,  0.        ,  0.60025858],
       [ 1.19326493,  0.3776364 ,  0.81352455,  0.60025858,  0.        ]])
K
array([[ 1.        ,  3.5465681 ,  2.67062441,  2.22752646,  3.29783084],
       [ 3.5465681 ,  1.        ,  2.06799756,  2.23935453,  1.45883242],
       [ 2.67062441,  2.06799756,  1.        ,  2.01789192,  2.25584482],
       [ 2.22752646,  2.23935453,  2.01789192,  1.        ,  1.82259002],
       [ 3.29783084,  1.45883242,  2.25584482,  1.82259002,  1.        ]])
```

Hoping this can help you. Good work

EDIT
You can also use only numpy array, for a theano implementaion:

```
dist = (X ** 2).sum(1).reshape((X.shape[0], 1)) + (X ** 2).sum(1).reshape((1, X.shape[0])) - 2 * X.dot(X.T)
```

It should be work!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping to be able to it in numpy since subsequently I'd like to do the same in Theano (I know, it's dead, but...). Thanks again for taking the time to respond.

Comment: This is the default approach for distance calculations. As you can this the return type of `cdist` is a numpy array.

Comment: Thanks for the edit about Theano. This indeed works in case `X` is of type `theano.tensor.fmatrix`, but I want to use it in case `X` is the output of a Lasagne layer, more specifically the output of the `lasagne.layers.GlobalPoolLayer`, which is 2-dimensional, and that it should work, but it doesn't. It says `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'GlobalPoolLayer' and 'int'
`. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked with `lasagne` library, may be you should to find a way to convert the `GlobalPoolLayer` into a `theano.tensor.fmatrix` or a way to extract the `fmatrix` from the `GlobalPoolLayer`.

Answer (score 6):

This is certainly possible in numpy alone if you harness the power of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

You just have to code out the inner distance-norm calculation in a vectorized way:

```
X1 = X[:, np.newaxis, :]
X2 = X[np.newaxis, :, :]
K = np.exp(-np.sum((X1 - X2)**2, axis=-1))
```

Answer (score 5):

**Don't vectorize it, just compile it**

This is nearly every time faster and the code is easier to read.
Since a good jit compiler like [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) is available, this is a really simple thing to do.

In your case:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def Test_1(X):
  K = np.zeros((B, B))
  for i in range(X.shape[0]):
      x_i = X[i, :]
      for j in range(X.shape[0]):
          x_j = X[j, :]
          K[i, j] = np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(x_i - x_j, 2) ** 2)

  return K
```

It is also very easy to parallelize functions:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def Test_1(X):
  K = np.zeros((B, B))
  for i in nb.prange(X.shape[0]):
      x_i = X[i, :]
      for j in range(X.shape[0]):
          x_j = X[j, :]
          K[i, j] = np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(x_i - x_j, 2) ** 2)

  return K
```

This easily outperforms all other solutions provided so far. The first function call takes about 0.5s longer, because here your code is compiled, but i guess you want to call this function more than one time.

If you use the single-threaded version, you could also cache the compilation results. The caching of multithreaded code will likely be implemented soon.