# Numpy array calculations take too long - Bug?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

NumPy version: 1.14.5

**Purpose of the 'foo' function:**

- Finding the Euclid distance between arrays with the shapes (1,512), which represent facial features.

**Issue:**

- foo function takes **~223.32 ms** , but after that, some background operations related to NumPy take **170 seconds** for some reason

**Question:**

Is keeping arrays in dictionaries, and iterating over them is a very **dangerous** usage of NumPy arrays?

**Request for an Advice:**

When I keep the arrays stacked and separate from dict, Euclid distance calculation takes half the time (~120ms instead of ~250ms), but overall performance doesn't change much for some reason. Allocating new arrays and stacking them may have countered the benefits of bigger array calculations.
I am open to any advice.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import time
import uuid
import random
from funcy import print_durations

@print_durations
def foo(merged_faces_rec, face):
    t = time.time()
    for uid, feature_list in merged_faces_rec.items():
        dist = np.linalg.norm( np.subtract(feature_list[0], face))
    print("foo inside : ", time.time()-t)

rand_age = lambda : random.choice(["0-18", "18-35", "35-55", "55+"])
rand_gender = lambda : random.choice(["Erkek", "Kadin"])
rand_emo = lambda : random.choice(["happy", "sad", "neutral", "scared"])
date_list = []
emb = lambda : np.random.rand(1, 512)

def generate_faces_rec(d, n=12000):
    for _ in range(n):
        d[uuid.uuid4().hex] = [emb(), rand_gender(), rand_age(), rand_emo(), date_list]

faces_rec1 = dict()
generate_faces_rec(faces_rec1)
faces_rec2 = dict()
generate_faces_rec(faces_rec2)
faces_rec3 = dict()
generate_faces_rec(faces_rec3)
faces_rec4 = dict()
generate_faces_rec(faces_rec4)
faces_rec5 = dict()
generate_faces_rec(faces_rec5)

merged_faces_rec = dict()
st = time.time()
merged_faces_rec.update(faces_rec1)
merged_faces_rec.update(faces_rec2)
merged_faces_rec.update(faces_rec3)
merged_faces_rec.update(faces_rec4)
merged_faces_rec.update(faces_rec5)
t2 = time.time()
print("updates: ", t2-st)
face = list(merged_faces_rec.values())[0][0]
t3 = time.time()
print("face: ", t3-t2)

t4 = time.time()
foo(merged_faces_rec, face)
t5 = time.time()
print("foo: ", t5-t4)
```

**Result:**

Computations between t4 and t5 took 168 seconds.

```
updates:  0.00468754768371582
face:  0.0011434555053710938
foo inside :  0.2232837677001953
  223.32 ms in foo({'d02d46999aa145be8116..., [[0.96475353 0.8055263...)
foo:  168.42408967018127
```

**cProfile**

```
python3 -m cProfile -s tottime test.py
```

**cProfile Result:**

```
   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 30720512   44.991    0.000   85.425    0.000 arrayprint.py:888(__call__)
 36791296   42.447    0.000   42.447    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.dragon4_positional}
30840514/60001   36.154    0.000  149.749    0.002 arrayprint.py:659(recurser)
 24649728   25.967    0.000   25.967    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.dragon4_scientific}
 30720512   20.183    0.000   26.420    0.000 arrayprint.py:636(_extendLine)
       10   12.281    1.228   12.281    1.228 {method 'sub' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
    60001   11.434    0.000   79.370    0.001 arrayprint.py:804(fillFormat)
228330011/228329975   10.270    0.000   10.270    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
   204081    4.815    0.000   16.469    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
 18431577    4.624    0.000   21.742    0.000 arrayprint.py:854(<genexpr>)
 18431577    4.453    0.000   28.627    0.000 arrayprint.py:859(<genexpr>)
 30720531    3.987    0.000    3.987    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
 12348936    3.012    0.000   13.873    0.000 arrayprint.py:829(<genexpr>)
 12348936    3.007    0.000   17.955    0.000 arrayprint.py:832(<genexpr>)
 18431577    2.179    0.000    2.941    0.000 arrayprint.py:863(<genexpr>)
 18431577    2.124    0.000    2.870    0.000 arrayprint.py:864(<genexpr>)
 12348936    1.625    0.000    3.180    0.000 arrayprint.py:833(<genexpr>)
 12348936    1.468    0.000    1.992    0.000 arrayprint.py:834(<genexpr>)
 12348936    1.433    0.000    1.922    0.000 arrayprint.py:844(<genexpr>)
 12348936    1.432    0.000    1.929    0.000 arrayprint.py:837(<genexpr>)
 12324864    1.074    0.000    1.074    0.000 {method 'partition' of 'str' objects}
  6845518    0.761    0.000    0.761    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
    60001    0.747    0.000   80.175    0.001 arrayprint.py:777(__init__)
        2    0.637    0.319  245.563  122.782 debug.py:237(smart_repr)
   120002    0.573    0.000    0.573    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
    60001    0.421    0.000  231.153    0.004 arrayprint.py:436(_array2string)
    60000    0.370    0.000    0.370    0.000 {method 'rand' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}
    60000    0.303    0.000  232.641    0.004 arrayprint.py:1334(array_repr)
    60001    0.274    0.000  232.208    0.004 arrayprint.py:465(array2string)
    60001    0.261    0.000   80.780    0.001 arrayprint.py:367(_get_format_function)
   120008    0.255    0.000    0.611    0.000 numeric.py:2460(seterr)
```

**Update to Clearify the Question**

This is the part that has the **bug.** Something behind the scenes causes to program to take too long. Is it something to do with garbage collector, or just weird numpy bug? I don't have any clue.

```
t6 = time.time()
foo1(big_array, face) # 223.32ms
t7 = time.time()
print("foo1 : ", t7-t6) # foo1 : 170 seconds
```

Comment: In order to performe a pair wise distance, I suggest to use a matrix representation. Have a look to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48907216/efficient-computation-of-similarity-matrix-in-python-numpy/48907717#48907717, in which the similarity matrix has been computed with theano

Comment: Good advice, thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: by the way there is also a tensorflow version (vs 1.x) available on git: https://gist.github.com/mbsariyildiz/34cdc26afb630e8cae079048eef91865

Comment: Thank you for the advice! However my main question was about a bug that i discovered. Do you know how to solve it? I updated the question.